# perl unlink fails for file with special characters

Tags: perl, special-characters, unlink

Unix system is hosting shared folders for Windows workstations.
I wrote a script to delete old temp files that MS products create; but it does not work.
I wrote this code snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

 my $fn = '~$557.222 King Street.doc';
 system( 'touch', $fn );
 system( 'ls -l *.doc' );
 unlink '$fn' or warn "$! $fn";
```

This script produces:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 fbax  fbax  0 May 18 21:33 ~$557.222 King Street.doc
No such file or directory ~$557.222 King Street.doc at ../qTest.pl line 8.
```

I tried many many variations; they all failed. How can I make unlink delete this file?

Comment: As a starter: remove the single quotes around  `'$fn'` in the `unlink` command. Otherwise, you are trying to delete a file called `$fn` rather than the actual file.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that in my original code; but turns out there was another coding error in that script. :( All fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

`'$fn'` produces the three-character string `$fn` rather the value of variable `$fn`. Replace

```
unlink '$fn'
```

with

```
unlink $fn
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm testing lines such as `unlink` or `rename`, I'll often start by using `print` instead so I can see the arguments before I do something stupid. With that you'd immediately see the problem:

```
# unlink '$fn' or warn ...
print '$fn' or warn ...
```

This is one place I get to use `$,`, the variable that holds the string that `print` puts between arguments (`$"` is what double quoted strings use, which is different):

```
 # unlink @items or warn ...
 local $, = ' ';
 print @items or warn ...
```